# "Productively normal" space

Tags: gn.general-topology

If a set $S$ is endowed with the discrete topology $\mathcal{P}(S)$, then for every normal space $N$ the product $S\times N$ is normal.

**Question**: can we endow a set $S$ with another Hausdorff topology, such that still for all normal spaces $N$ the product $S\times N$ is normal.

Comment: I suppose you want to require the Hausdorff condition? If not, the indiscrete topology seems to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is no. It was proved by Mary Ellen Rudin in *$\aleph$-Dowker spaces* (1978) that for any non-discrete Hausdorff space $S$ there is a normal Hausdorff space $N$ such that $S\times N$ is not normal, thus solving in the affirmative [Morita´s first conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_conjectures).

Comment: Full citation: Rudin, Mary Ellen.  $\aleph$-Dowker spaces.  *Czechoslovak Math. J.* **28** (103) (1978), no. 2, 324–326.   [MR 478098](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=478098)

Comment: although not exactly your question, you (the OP) may want to know about interest in recent years in productively Lindelof spaces, google it or see MSE question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730240/a-question-about-productively-lindel%C3%B6f-metrizable-spaces